# List selector android

Tags: android

I've got two shapes like this:

**List_selector_focused.xml**

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#f5c98c"
    android:endColor="#f7ddb8"
    android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

and **list_selector_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#fb9d23"
    android:endColor="#ffc579"
    android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

and my list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_focused" />

<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

And to my listview, I add the `list_selector.xml`

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#0A3A5C"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
```

But there is no color appearing when i press one of the items in the listview, any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The list I try to apply this to, is a custom list. The layout for each of the items in the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First"
    android:textColor="#11629F"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/idNumber"
    android:layout_below="@+id/idNumber"
    android:text="Second"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What `@android:color/transparent`, `@drawable/list_selector_focused` and `@drawable/list_selector_pressed` contains?

Comment: @Tobias Moe Thorstensen Try two things. First: set your listiew clickable and longClickable atributes to true and report. Second: Try registering yout listview for contextmenu via registerForContextMenu(). If you have to implement dummy listener. Report your findings.

Answer (score 2):

Do your Items have a constant background color? If so, your selector is not going to be displayed, since this selector is set on the back of your item. Make sure your item's background is transparent when selected, in order to have your selector visible.

Comment: What items? The items in the list? Where should I specify this?

Comment: In the XML of these item, under your layout folder. Or, are you using a resource provided by the Android platform? I am not sure if this is the fix to your problem, but it might be.

Comment: Yes, and it has no background color, so the bug has to be anywhere else. Your item views are focusable, aren't they?